# iOS UIButton subclass setTitle forState not called from storyboard

Tags: ios, uikit, uibutton, storyboard

I have a `CustomButton: UIButton` that overrides `setTitle:forState:` and `setAttributedTitle:forState:`.

When I use this button in a storyboard file and set the text via storyboard, neither `setTitle` or `setAttributedTitle` in the subclass is called.

Is storyboard supposed to call these methods on the subclass, or does it only call it on the base class `UIButton` when the title is not set programmatically?

Comment: Storyboard will use the `init(coder:)` initialiser to create objects. It is likely that this initialise for UIButton will set the buttons internal state directly rather than incur the overhead of calling the various methods.

Comment: Show us the code you've written... this works fine in Storyboard for me: https://pastebin.com/vU4WauEb